# waiting for binaries to complete in shell script

Tags: shell

I am writing a shell script in which i need to call a binary three times and i need to transfer the call to main program once all these three binaries have completed. I think I need to use fork and wait in my shell script. I am not sure how to implement fork, wait and exec in shell script. I would like to know some good tutorial where I can read these in good detail.

Thanks you so much for help in advance.

Comment: If you don't need the 3 binaries to run concurrently, just call them one at a time in your script.

Comment: I need to run all three binaries in parallel and then need to wait all three are completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using bash (or ksh, or others) as your shell, then this is how you "fork" and wait:

```
command_one&
command_two -options&
command_three lots of args&

wait
```

Using an `&` after a command makes it execute in the background; elsewise the shell will wait after each command. `wait` with no args waits for all jobs, i.e. children.
`$ help wait jobs` and the man page for bash can give you more insight into job management.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you please explain me how to achieve same in perl

Comment: I'm sorry. I have forgotten everything I knew in Perl, except regexps. I think, looking at the documentation for the `exec` function would help.

Comment: this answer also applies to ksh88 and ksh93 (and likely pdksh). Not intended to be an all inclusive list, zsh is very likely too, there may be others. Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks. I just didn't want to get someone's hopes up with a shell I don't know.

Comment: This applies to every version of sh ever implemented!  Even /bin/sh on Solaris 0.0-beta would recognize this and behave correctly.

Comment: Cool. After seeing all that sh can't do--looking inside of ./configure scripts, which are portable~nasty--I am surprised.